# What was the name of the graphic novel with perfume-mixing people and a walking egg?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I suddenly got a flashback about this comic, which must've been from around 80s-90s. The only things I can manage to remember from it are that there was the protagonist who tried to blend in a strange city (not from this world). He met its inhabitants and tried to make a correct perfume (?) mixture for conveying his emotions, but he failed, the mixture smelling foul. There was also a companion, a small walking egg. If someone actually manages to recognise the comic from this very bad description, he/she will have my everlasting gratitude.

Comment: I just checked his work - it wasn't him. This comic had a feeling that it was drawn by a French artist. Thanks for replying anyway! :)